# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, invalid selection start: 24, null, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: invalid selection start: 24

Tags: flutter, textfield

Whenever I try to clear the TextField by clicking on the IconButton I get an Unhandled Exception warning in the debug console although my TextField is cleared.
Also when I try to add a new value to the TextField my previous value is automatically displayed in the TextField.
Here's my code for the Search_location UI

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:maps_app/models/place.dart';
import 'package:maps_app/services/location_api.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchViewState createState() => _SearchViewState();
}

class _SearchViewState extends State<SearchView> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  var latitude, longitude;
  var con_width = 0.0;
  var list_height = 0.0;
  GeoFirePoint point;
  Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

  getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      final pos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      setState(() {
        latitude = pos.latitude;
        longitude = pos.longitude;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SearchInjector(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Consumer<LocationApi>(
            builder: (_, api, child) => SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: TextField(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            list_height = 56;
                          });
                        },
                        controller: api.addressController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // getCurrentLocation();
                                }),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    api.addressController.clear();
                                    con_width = 0.0;
                                    list_height = 0.0;
                                  });
                                }),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            ),
                            labelText: 'Search Location',
                            fillColor: Colors.grey[20],
                            filled: true),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            con_width = 300.0;
                          });
                          api.places.clear();
                          api.handleSearch(value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 20),
                        height: list_height,
                        color: Colors.blue[100].withOpacity(.3),
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Column(
                            children: List.generate(1, (i) {
                          return ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                api.addressController.text = 'Your Location';
                                list_height = 0.0;
                                con_width = 0.0;
                              });
                            },
                            title: Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.my_location),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Your Location',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }))),
                    AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 20),
                      color: Colors.blue[100].withOpacity(.3),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: con_width,
                      child: StreamBuilder<List<Place>>(
                          stream: api.controllerOut,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.data == null) {
                              return Center(
                                  child: Text('No data address found'));
                            }
                            final data = snapshot.data;
                            return Scrollbar(
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                controller: _scrollController,
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                            children: List.generate(data.length,
                                                (index) {
                                          final place = data[index];
                                          return ListTile(
                                            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                                            onTap: () {
                                              point = geo.point(
                                                  latitude: place.latitude,
                                                  longitude: place.longitude);
                                              setState(() {
                                                api.addressController.text =
                                                    '${place.name}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.country}, ${place.postalCode}';
                                                con_width = 0.0;
                                                list_height = 0.0;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            title: Text(
                                                '${place.name}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode} '),
                                            subtitle: Text(
                                                '${place.adminArea}, ${place.country}'),
                                          );
                                        })),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchInjector extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const SearchInjector({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => LocationApi(),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Exception I am getting in the debug Console

```
Restarted application in 1,268ms.
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: invalid selection start: 13
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$TextEditState.<init>(TextInputChannel.java:724)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$TextEditState.fromJson(TextInputChannel.java:680)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$1.onMethodCall(TextInputChannel.java:91)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/textinput(29061):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
E/flutter (29061): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, invalid selection start: 13, null, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: invalid selection start: 13
E/flutter (29061):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$TextEditState.<init>(TextInputChannel.java:724)
E/flutter (29061):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$TextEditState.fromJson(TextInputChannel.java:680)
E/flutter (29061):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$1.onMethodCall(TextInputChannel.java:91)
E/flutter (29061):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (29061):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (29061):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/flutter (29061):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (29061):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (29061):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/flutter (29061):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
E/flutter (29061):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (29061):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
E/flutter (29061):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
E/flutter (29061): )
[38;5;244mE/flutter (29061): #0      JSONMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (29061): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod[39;49m
E/flutter (29061): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29061):
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the clearing of the controller.

Instead of

```
api.addressController.clear();
```

try:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => api.addressController.clear());
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you are trying to access index which does not exists, please try to check your list size.